# Images stored in Imgur loading very slow on my website

Tags: performance, next.js

I am currently housing my images on Imgur and they take about 2 seconds to load.  I am using the Imgur URL of my image as the image source for my code.  Is there anyway I can get them to load faster? I am currently working in Next.JS

Comment: Do they load at page start or can you improve perceived loading time by preloading them before they actually need to be displayed? Are they being loaded on a dynamically generated page or a static page?

Comment: Are you loading the images through javascript somehow or with a html <img> tag?

Comment: @TheZachMan through an html tag

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a service worker to cache the images on first load and then serve them up to your app.

This way, on subsequent loads, they'll be fetched from the cache (not the source) and it'll be almost instantaneous...

Here's a good start to learning about service workers https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Comment: Thanks so much let me give it a try!

Comment: No problem... if it helps... kindly upvote it and if it solves your problem... drop that sweet green tick... :)